# GCC Troubles: CentOS 7

Tags: gcc, centos

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to install a program called mapnik from source on CentOS 7. When I run ./configure I get the following error.

```
 C++ compiler does not support C++11 standard (-std=c++11), which is required. Please upgrade your compiler to at least g++ 4.7 (ideally 4.8)
```

Unfortunately its not as simple as just updating gcc because when I run:

```
 gcc --version
```

I get:

```
 gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the config.log file in the directory where you ran `configure`. It should contain more info, including what the script tried and how it failed.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your GCC version is from 2013, so there is certainly room for update.

Furthermore(i might be mistaken here), don't you need g++ to compile C++? This would work the following way:

```
sudo yum install g++
```

Comment: I don't believe that's it, but thank you for your answer. When I run `yum install gcc-c++` I get `Package gcc-c++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. This is because I believe all of this was group installed from "Development Tools".

Comment: Okay, no need to downvote. How about if you pass the flags to compile with C++11, with -std=c++11?

Comment: I don't have voting privileges on this site yet, but I will try that.

Comment: Also, following a thread on the official GitHub page of Mapnik, this solution looks like it will do the trick `./configure CXX=g++-4.8 CC=gcc-4.8`

Answer (score 0):

**The Soultion:**

I ended up just removing all of *Mapnik* which I cloned from their git page, and instead downloaded the latest *tar.gz* version. From there I just installed like normal and it worked. Not the most intuitive fix, but it did the job.